# trouble with execute an command at apache exec in java

Tags: java, apache

i want to run a file (a.txt) by using **apache commons exec** libraries . but it gives me this error : what is problem?

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "a.txt" (in directory "C:\Users\sinaa\Desktop"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

my code is :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    File temp=new File("C:\\Users\\sinaa\\Desktop");
    exec.setWorkingDirectory(temp);
    CommandLine s=new CommandLine("a.txt");
    exec.execute(s);
}
```

Comment: You are sure that file exists on your desktop? What do you mean by "run"?

Comment: yes i'm sure. i mean i want to open a.txt in notepad window when i compile the code.

Comment: Do you mean a.txt isn't a script? You want to just open the a.txt in Notepad?

Comment: yes . same as command prompt when in the specified directory i type a.txt  and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> i want to open a.txt in notepad window when i compile the code

To open up a File in Java using the default associated application, use the [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class:

```
try{
    Desktop.open("a.txt");
}catch(IOException io){
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: but i want to do this with apache commons exec.

Comment: Why is that a requirement?